# Tensorflow Edge Detection Layer for Augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, canny-operator

I am trying to create a Tensorflow Custom Layer to perform Edge Detection using OpenCV's Canny method...

```
class Canny(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        canny = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200)
        return canny
```

Clearly the above won't work because 'x' isn't an numpy array, its a collection of Tensors. I have looked through API and read some of the code for existing functions like RandomFlip and I don't see how I can go from this collection of Tensors to a OpenCV single image processor, then back out to a collection. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that stuff is not differentiable. if this is just for augmentation (to generate training data), it should be fine, but this ***can't*** show up in an actual network. -- you need to convert from tf.Tensor to numpy array, for the opencv API, and then from numpy array back to tf.Tensor. you need to process each image of the batch individually, so yes, there's gonna be a loop. also: NCHW/NHWC -- Canny has no business showing up in any deep learning pipeline. please explain the goal (no, using canny is not the goal) and solicit suggested approaches. if "Canny" is the answer, the question is wrong.

Comment: I am doing image classification, which isn't going well with the images as they are.  One idea is to classify not the original image but images that just show the "cracks", aka the features we are classifying on are mostly related to cracks or lines in the image.  The idea is that this is a form of noise reduction.

Comment: Any reason you seemingly can't pre-process all your images with the edge detector via OpenCV and feed that output to the NN instead?

Comment: canny is terrible. it loses so much information and the result isn't smooth either. you might as well feed in randomness. canny will ruin EVERYTHING. I can't stress this enough. it might sound dramatic but canny is like an atomic bomb. -- just apply a highpass filter (laplacian). those are differentiable because they're just convolutions.

Comment: StateMachine, just the size of the dataset its almost a TB and I didn't want to store two copies of it so I was hoping to do the transformation at runtime.  However, I have already started down that road just to test.

Comment: Christoph, okay but what is the harm of trying?  For my particular problem Canny seems to drop a lot of the noise making it easier to classify (at least as a human).  Couldn't you argue turning the image grey does the same thing.